# Is there any security flaw in using a non root port in production?

Tags: webserver, web-service, ports

I am planning to use a web service running on port 8080 for serving some static files in production . Is it acceptable or is there any possible security flaw in this?
NOTE- I don't want this service to be proxied via port 80 or 443.

Comment: There will be some users out there that wont be able to reach this server.
Not every proxy or firewall allow traffic to port 8080.

Comment: While answers echo using port 8080 is confusing/exotic I highly disagree with this. As 8080 is an acceptable alternative for serving data/files through a web service. https://www.grc.com/port_8080.htm

Answer (score 1):

Same as @JOW +

Using exotics ports may be a bit confusing if your networks get bigger...

Nevertheless, in a pure "security" perspective, there's no problem with use of unprivileged ports. In fact, in the past, using ports >1024 was to run service as non-root users...
Nowadays, most of servers can do privileges dropping after binding IP ports, it became a bit useless.

But if you intend to run *crappy-home-made-service*, i think use of unprivileged port is better than running as root :)

Comment: Privileged ports are commonly used services that could require you to authenticate with credentials for the server - like ssh or ftp. Image if anyone could listen to ports used by these common services. A rouge user could easily harvest usernames and passwords. I do not think privileged ports are useless.

Comment: This is not an exotic port. 8080 is an acceptable alternative for serving data/files through a web service. https://www.grc.com/port_8080.htm

Answer (score 1):

There is no intrinsic security issue with using a non-standard port number.

However if this is being done to avoid security restrictions or would bypass the controls / monitoring in place for the expected port for a service, then you are undermining the network security.

Answer (score 0):

There is no harm *per se* in using a non standard port. As others have already said, some of your users may not be able to reach it if they are behing a firewall and it is not an internal web service.

But IMHO there is a security problem with your design and it it not related to the use of a non standard port. But you write

> I don't want this service to be proxied via port 80 or 443

I hope you have strong reasons for that and you understand the implications. Best practices recommend that web applications are hidden behind a reverse proxy, because the reverse proxy is a much simpler animal with a reduced exposed surface. For that reason it is supposed to contain  less security flaws, and less risks of crash facing abnormal queries.

TL/DR: the only security problem I see here is not using a reverse proxy (on standard ports) to hide the web service.

Answer (score -1):

Except for HTTP/HTTPS ports, if you are using any other [well known Ports](http://www.webopedia.com/quick_ref/portnumbers.asp), then you may be interfering with other Services in your network. Otherwise the Port used doesn't really matter. There are no security flaws with using a non-standard port. But you should take care to secure the web-service listening in that 8080 Port as it runs in the Application layer of OSI Model.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which is specifically asking about security flaws.   General network and administrative issues this may cause are out of scope.

Comment: @Xander I don't see any security flaws with using a non standard port. If others know of security flaws, they'll answer, i guess.

Comment: Its a very confused and confusing response

Comment: The last paragraph is moot since the sysadmin blocking this port isn't a security issue.

Comment: i've now removed the irrelavent and confusing Para